# How to open downloads app in android after clicking on notification using DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-download-manager

Here i used DownloadManger to download and it will show the progress in Notification bar

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
            request.setTitle("Data Download");
            //Setting description of request
            request.setDescription("Android Data download using DownloadManager.");
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, filter);
```

Broadcast receiver to receive click action(DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED) during downloading and the action is working during download

```
private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED.equals(action))
            {
               startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
            }


        }
    };
```

but after download DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED is not working to redirect to downloads app. 
Can any one help me how can i redirect after clicking on DownloadManger notification(after complete download) to downloads app  ????????????

Comment: dont forget to add intent filter in manifest
`<receiver android:name="your claas name">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"></action>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>`

and in intent 
`
Intent i = new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i); `

Comment: @Muklas   After downloading completes, Does action events like clicking working on navigation works ? I've checked it, clicking on it is opening the download instead of redirecting to downloads apps. can you help me out on this thing please............

Comment: @Batman did you find solution for this?

Comment: After writing the file, if i open the downloads folder programmatically using startActivity(Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS)). File is not visible. But if i open from file explorer of phone, then the file is visible. Any idea, why this is happening ?